# Extract data from a table-like structure using python

Tags: python

I would like to get a numeric or alphanumeric character from a table-like structure

This table-like structure may contain some rubbish data or unorganized data

For Example,

```
''' 5. Item | 6.Marks and 7. Numberand kind of packages; 8. Ori 9. Quantity (Gross weight or 10. Invoice
number ` numbers on description of goods including Conferring other measurement), and number(s)
packages HS Code (6 digits) and brand Criterion (see value (FOB) where RVC is and date of cnaommep(ainyf apipslsiucianbglet)h.irNdapmaertoyf Overleaf Notes) appppilied (see.Overilseaaff NoNtoteess)), minvvooice(s)
invoice UF applicable)
 91501937'''
```

The goal is to get the numeric number under the field **invoice**
which is **91501937**

Here this is an output from an OCR and I have the locations

This is how it looks like in the Searchable PDF formate.
[image]

The Problem here that Regex was not valid I tried `tabula` but this structure is considered rubbish for `tabula`

Tried some Regex Like `re.search(r'(invvooice(s)).*(\d+)',first_string,re.DOTALL)` but is very with regex and can get anything.

Comment: I'm struggling with understanding what you are trying to do. do you want a specific character from the line or are you trying to split the messy text into different strings and putting them into a list?

Comment: @Stanley I edited the post. i would like to get the numeric value under the cell Invoice

Answer (score 1):

> Took me a while but i figured it out at last. I wrote this code assuming the invoice number would always be at last, but it shouldnt be hard to edit it so it can be other places aswell.

**Here is my solution**

```
x =  "5. Item | 6.Marks and 7. Numberand kind of packages; 8. Ori 9. Quantity (Gross weight or 10. Invoice number ` numbers on description of goods including Conferring other measurement), and number(s) packages HS Code (6 digits) and brand Criterion (see value (FOB) where RVC is and date of cnaommep(ainyf apipslsiucianbglet)h.irNdapmaertoyf Overleaf Notes) appppilied (see.Overilseaaff NoNtoteess)), minvvooice(s) invoice UF applicable)  91501937"

a = x.lower()
words = a.split()
wordlist = []
for word in words:
    wordlist.append(word)

number = 0

for n in a:
    try:
        print('word number %d: %s' %(number,wordlist[number]))
        number = number + 1
    except IndexError:
        break


print('here is your number: %s' %(wordlist[-1]))
```

> **Edit** You dont need the part of the code that is `for n in a` it's only for tracking my progress

Comment: This is good but the place may be dynamic . Number is not always at the last and the position is not a known info

Comment: could you give me more examples? i need a known shared factor to be able to distinguish between whats what, also upvotes on the post is greatly appreaciated!